# Message from docker container : SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have a node.js server and a database `TestMetricsDB` **without** a password.

My node.js server can connect to the server with this url :

```
POSTGRESS_URL=postgresql://postgres:@192.168.230.138:5432/TestMetricsDB
```

So far, everything works as expected, my server connects to the database.

But when I try to run the server from a docker container, it doesn't work anymore.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e POSTGRESS_URL=postgresql://postgres@192.168.230.138:5432/TestMetricsDB testmetricswebapp:latest

[2023/05/18 00:09:01] [ERROR] PostgreSQL connection error: Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string
    at Object.continueSession (/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/sasl.js:24:11)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:272:18)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at /app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:12
    at Parser.parse (/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:332:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:305:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:242:10)
```